# Async nature of ElasticSearch Java API

Tags: java, groovy, elasticsearch

Wanna write integration tests for elasticSearch service:
1. Index
2. Search
3. Check result

Each Java api method is executed asynchronously. How can I make it as simple sync api: call `api.a`, waiting for result, call `api.b`, waiting for result...

Comment: What testing framework are you using? This question needs alot more information.

Comment: Spock framework. But I think problem doesn't depends on testing framework. How can I wait for result of elasticSearch api call?

Comment: Hm, I was typing a response about how to use Futures and such, but I suspect that your question is actually about how to create an infrastructure to be notified of indexing results asynchronously. That depends strongly on your search engine's architecture, and is actually pretty tangential to testing. We need more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @loteq mentioned, you can simply call `.actionGet()` on a `Future` to make it synchronous. Check [elasticsearch integration tests](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/1.4/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/exists/SimpleExistsTests.java), they have some very good examples.