# Elasticsearch strange behaviour for queries straight after insertion

Tags: elasticsearch

I am writing some integration tests for an app that uses Elasticsearch and I am experiencing a strange behaviour. If I insert a document and I query straight after that, I get different results every time. 
I suspect that, albeit the insertion itself will return, the indexing itself doesn't take place synchronously and, because of that, the query will experiment a race condition with unpredictable results.

*If this is the case:* is there a way to synchronize, so that when I run my queries, I know that they are ready and successful???

More details: I am using elasticsearch embedded and the query is a simple filter. The only odd thing is that I am using template files for the document model.

EDIT: I even tried to GET the document by ID after insertion, but the queries still return random results (unless I put a thread Sleep to wait some seconds).

Comment: i assume that you are using the java api. this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766562/async-nature-of-elasticsearch-java-api

Comment: No it is the REST api, however I found the reason

Comment: I don't suppose you could mention the reason, @gotch4 - I think we are having the same problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Elasticsearch docs for the index API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html):

> refresh
>
> To refresh the index immediately after the operation occurs, so that
>   the document appears in search results immediately, the refresh
>   parameter can be set to true. Setting this option to true should ONLY
>   be done after careful thought and verification that it does not lead
>   to poor performance, both from an indexing and a search standpoint.
>   Note, getting a document using the get API is completely realtime.

That's why my queries were returning weird results. Because indexing was sometimes not yet completed. Also, it is possible to do a refresh not as part of an insertion, [using the `_refresh` endpoint](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html):

```
$ curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/_refresh'
```